# Porting old MDX code

Tags: sharpdx

I'm porting some old MDX code to SharpDX using Direct3D9 assemblies.

I was able to 'convert' most of the code to SharpDX but I'm stuck at the following:

```
Mesh result = Mesh.Cylinder(_device, _arrowRadius1, _arrowRadius2, _arrowLength, _arrowNumberOfSlices, _arrowNumberOfStacks);

Mesh result = Mesh.Box(_device, _axisLength, _axisThick, _axisThick);

Mesh.TextFromFont(_device, new System.Drawing.Font("Berlin Sans FB", 12), text, 5f, 0.2f);
```

The mesh class exists but does not contain the Cylinder or Box methods. I've gone through tons of documentation and could not find a solution.

Apart from the problem with the Mesh class I could not find matching classes and  methods for the following in SharpDX:

```
using (Surface backbuffer = _device.GetBackBuffer(0, 0))
{
    GraphicsStream stream = SurfaceLoader.SaveToStream(ImageFileFormat.Bmp, backbuffer);
    return new Bitmap(stream);
}
```

`GraphicStream` and `SurfaceLoader` do not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had similar problem proting from old Managed Microsoft.DirectX to SharpDx9.
For Meshes we had to implement our own Mesh classes since there are no pritives like cylinder, sphere or box in SharpDx.Mesh (its just a mock class i guess).
But for SurfaceLoader check Surface class itself it has static methods that will probably match your needs. For example:

Surface.ToStream()